# How to loop over each id in qlik sense to get a minimum and maximum of his related data

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a table full of patients visits and record and need to load on qlik sense.

But what I want is to create a table that take each patient id and do the following:

1. Take the minimum date (first visit) and the related test result of it;
2. Take the maximum date (last visit) and its related test result;
3. Then display a table having: patient id, min date, min date test result, max date, max date result.

I tried the following:

```
LOAD 
    Min(Date([test_date])) as mindate,
    test_result,
    beneficiary_id
    //Max(Date([test_date])) as  maxdate,
Resident [full_table]
group by beneficiary_id;
```

And the same for maximum date, but the table took the same min and max for all patients.

Comment: Just to be clear, your mindate and maxdate are separated? Also what problem(s) are your running into?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the patient_id.

From what it looks like, you are grouping by the beneficiary_id. Not sure if this is a site or vendor, but you should include a reference to a patient ID, if that's the level of granularity you need for the min() and max() dates.